# When I try to submit a PHP form from my web (on render.com) I get this error:

Tags: php, forms, deployment, render, autoload

When I try to submit a PHP form from my web I get this error:

Warning : require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/…/symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41

Fatal error : require(): Failed opening required ‘/var/www/html/vendor/composer/…/symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php’ (include_path=‘.:/usr/local/lib/php’) in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41

The form works fine when testing on my local environment using XAMPP. I should receive an email to my gmail address.

I should receive the form content to my gmail. I tried many things. The files are in place.

Comment: `The files are in place`...respectfully, PHP disagrees with you, and it cannot lie. Double-check that the files exist on the webserver _and_ are in the right place.

Comment: does the www user on the machine have read privileges on the directory ?  is the owner of 'vendor' directory same as owner of other php files in document root ?

Comment: @ADyson is right. Try to run `rm -rf vendor && composer update -v` on your web server inside the web root.

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile wasn't set up correct. After the updaes it works fine. Here is it if anyone neeeds to see it.

```
//Use an official PHP runtime as the base image

FROM php:7.4-apache

//Set the working directory in the container

WORKDIR /var/www/html

//Copy just the necessary files for Composer installation

COPY composer.json composer.lock /var/www/html/

//Install Composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

//Install project dependencies with Composer

RUN composer install --no-dev

//Copy the rest of your PHP files to the container

COPY . /var/www/html

//Expose port 80 for the Apache web server

EXPOSE 80

//Start the Apache web server

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```